# VB.NET overload default functionality when user clicks the X (Close Program)

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, event-handling, overriding

How do I go about overriding the default functionality when a user clicks the X in a VB.NET form-based application?

I am currently handling the MyBase.Closing event... but since it's a DirectX app, I need to do some cleanup before allowing the form the close.

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail about why the Closing event is not good enough for this situation?

Comment: I need to post a Program-Close Event to our Custom Event Manager so that the application can shutdown in a manner that is clean. A number of things need to be unwound or cleaned up such as any unsaved data or connections to the server or other clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do some extra clean up before a form closes, do so in the form's [Form Closing event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx).

This event also allows you to cancel the form close through the event's [FormClosingEventArgs.Cancel property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel.aspx).  The event's [CloseReason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.closereason.aspx) property will tell you why the event was called (you'd check for [CloseReason.UserClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason.aspx))

Comment: This is not an option for this application. I need to do some cleanup when the user clicks X and this cleanup cannot be initiated from the Closing Event. My question relates to overriding the functionality of the X button.

Comment: The form doesn't have to close when the Form Closing event fires.  You can cancel it.  That wouldn't suit your needs?

Comment: That wouldn't not suit my needs

Comment: @Jay Riggs: -1*(-1) for the smart double negation answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Re your other comments; doing anything *before* the event has fired would be premature; after all, some other code *might* cancel the close, and you'd be left with a scuppered form. Personally, I'd be tempted to override `OnClosed`; not much of a VB head, but in C#:

```
    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // check OK to close (save/cancel etc)
        base.OnClosing(e);
    }
    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        // your code here
        base.OnClosed(e);
        // or here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't feel comfortable putting your code in the Form_Closing event, the only other option I am aware of is a "hack" that I've used once or twice.  It should not be necessary to resort to this hack, but here it is:

---

Don't use the normal close button.  Instead, create your form so that it has no ControlBox.  You can do this by setting ControlBox = false on the form, in which case, you will still have the normal bar across the top of the form, or you can set the form's FormBorderStyle to "None. If you go this second route, there will be no bar across the top, or any other visible border, so you'll have to simulate those either by drawing on the form, or by artistic use of Panel controls.

Then you can add a standard button and make it ***look*** like a close button, and put your clean-up code in there.  At the end of the button event, just call `this.Close()` (C#) or `Me.Close()` (VB)