# Override standard close (X) button in a Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I go about changing what happens when a user clicks the close (red X) button in a Windows Forms application (in C#)?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You can override [OnFormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onformclosing.aspx) to do this. Just be careful you don't do anything too unexpected, as clicking the 'X' to close is a well understood behavior.

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnFormClosing(e);

    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown) return;

    // Confirm user wants to close
    switch (MessageBox.Show(this, "Are you sure you want to close?", "Closing", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
    {
    case DialogResult.No:
        e.Cancel = true;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }        
}
```

Comment: My guess is he wants to minimize to tray, but you get the +1 from me for saying be careful.

Comment: @Jon B - you should check the close reason.  If Windows is shutting down, you don't want to be showing message boxes.

Comment: I made it a switch statement so I don't have to scroll off to the right to read the right hand side of the `==`

Comment: @Philip: well, that depends. A "Do you want to save" box should be shown everytime it is relevant (there are changes) and canceling should cancel shutdown. That's what happens with VS, for example. An annoying "Do you want to close" should be shown... ideally, never, but if you're going that way, that one you should bypass on shutdown.

Comment: @Phillip - is this actually recommended? I believe most applications will ask you if you want to save changes to a modified file, regardless of the close reason.

Comment: Where I work recently got Vista and Windows 7 certification and this was a requirement.  See policy 7 from this document: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=27028822-b172-4cec-91a3-26b610a4da79

Comment: If you're worried about lost data on windows shutdown, you could always save to a temporary location and give the user a choice of restoring the data the next time the app is run.

Comment: Can I just add how stupid it is that you cannot differentiate between the user closing the form by clicking X (or using other parts of the built in UI), and by calling form.Close() from code...

Answer (score 21):

Override the [OnFormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onformclosing.aspx) method.

**CAUTION:**  You need to check the CloseReason and only alter the behaviour if it is UserClosing.  You should not put anything in here that would stall the Windows shutdown routine.

[Application Shutdown Changes in Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700677(VS.85).aspx)

This is from the [Windows 7 logo program requirements](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9630189).

Comment: Do they offer an exception if you are asking the user to save work before shutting down?

Answer (score 18):

One thing these answers lack, and which newbies are probably looking for, is that while it's nice to have an event:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // do something
}
```

It's not going to do anything at all unless you [register the event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events). Put this in the class constructor:

```
this.FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;
```

Comment: It worked for me without registering the event, but maybe it depends on the situation.

Answer (score 10):

Either override the [OnFormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onformclosing.aspx) or register for the event [FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx).

This is an example of overriding the OnFormClosing function in the derived form:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   e.Cancel = true;
}
```

This is an example of the handler of the event to stop the form from closing which can be in any class:

```
private void FormClosing(object sender,FormClosingEventArgs e)
{  
   e.Cancel = true;
}
```

To get more advanced, check the CloseReason property on the FormClosingEventArgs to ensure the appropriate action is performed. You might want to only do the alternative action if the user tries to close the form.

Answer (score 10):

as Jon B said, but you'll also want to check for the `ApplicationExitCall` and `TaskManagerClosing` CloseReason:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (  e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown 
        ||e.CloseReason == CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall
        ||e.CloseReason == CloseReason.TaskManagerClosing) { 
       return; 
    }
    e.Cancel = true;
    //assuming you want the close-button to only hide the form, 
    //and are overriding the form's OnFormClosing method:
    this.Hide();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Override [OnFormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onformclosing.aspx)?

Answer (score 3):

One situation where it is quite useful to be able to handle the x-button click event is when you are using a Form that is an MDI container. The reason is that the closeing and closed events are raised first with children and lastly with the parent. So in one scenario a user clicks the x-button to close the application and the MDI parent asks for a confirmation to proceed. In case he decides to not close the application but carry on whatever he is doing the children will already have processed the closing event potentially lost information/work whatever.
One solution is to intercept the WM_CLOSE message from the Windows message loop in your main application form (i.e. which closed, terminates the application) like so:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0010) // WM_CLOSE
        {
            // If we don't want to close this window 
            if (ShowConfirmation("Are you sure?") != DialogResult.Yes) return;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty commonly asked question.  One good answer is here:

[VB.NET overload default functionality when user clicks the X (Close Program)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562808/vb-net-overload-default-functionality-when-user-clicks-the-x-close-program)

---

If you don't feel comfortable putting your code in the Form_Closing event, the only other option I am aware of is a "hack" that I've used once or twice.  It should not be necessary to resort to this hack, but here it is:

---

Don't use the normal close button.  Instead, create your form so that it has no ControlBox.  You can do this by setting ControlBox = false on the form, in which case, you will still have the normal bar across the top of the form, or you can set the form's FormBorderStyle to "None. If you go this second route, there will be no bar across the top, or any other visible border, so you'll have to simulate those either by drawing on the form, or by artistic use of Panel controls.

Then you can add a standard button and make it ***look*** like a close button, and put your clean-up code in there.  At the end of the button event, just call `this.Close()` (C#) or `Me.Close()` (VB)

Comment: Why wouldn't one feel comfortable in handling the Closing event? IMHO adding a custom (but convincing) Close button is not so trivial (especially when you take transition effects and Aero stuff into account, which you normally get without any pain).

Comment: In the answer I linked to, the person whoposed the question didn't want to use the Form_Closing event for some reason.  I'm not sure what his reason was, but he didn't want to use it.  The times I used the hack, I just wanted a close button with a different look.

Comment: In other words the other answer was both linked to (fair enough) and copy-pasted, which is why half the answer is irrelevant and the rest recommends something that doesn't have any justification here.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works quite well. An alternative method that I have used is to create a FormClosing method for the main Form. This is very similar to the override. My example is for an application that minimizes to the system tray when clicking the close button on the Form.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }            
    }
```

This will allow **ALT+F4** or anything in the Application calling **Application.Exit();** to act as normal while clicking the (X) will minimize the Application.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks go to Jon.  I used this for a solution with multiple components.  When you closed the main form, some continued to run.  To close everything, I did this:

```
  protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
  {
   Environment.Exit(0);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys dataKey)
    {
        if (dataKey == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.Close();
            //this.Visible = false;
            //Plus clear values from form, if Visible false.
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, dataKey);
    }
```