# Event handler used to close a Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, validation, savechanges

I am trying to create an `event handler` such that when the user selects the `close` (x) button, it provides a prompt to the user to save any unsaved changes. Here is my `C#` code:

```
private void CloseFileOperation()
{
    // If the Spreadsheet has been changed since the user opened it and
    // the user has requested to Close the window, then prompt him to Save
    // the unsaved changes.
    if (SpreadSheet.Changed)
    {
        DialogResult UserChoice = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to save your changes?", "Spreadsheet Utility",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

        switch (UserChoice)
        {
            case DialogResult.Yes:
                SaveFileOperation();
                this.Close();
                break;
            case DialogResult.No:
                this.Close();
                break;
            case DialogResult.Cancel:
                return;
        }
    }

    // If the Spreadsheet hasn't been changed since the user opened it, then
    // simply Close the window.
    else
        this.Close();
}
```

I created and event handler `MainFram_FormClosing` that is triggered when the user selects the close (x) button.

```
private void MainFrame_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // Close the Spreadsheet.
    CloseFileOperation();
}
```

Whenever I select the close button the application crashes though.. I have read the replies from [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669318/override-standard-close-x-button-in-a-windows-form) post. I guess I am violating the [`Windows 7 Program Requirements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I guess I don't understand why this functionality can't be accomplished this easily.

What's the best approach at this?

Comment: Put a break point to your `MainFram_FormClosing` event and check.

Comment: If it was that easy it wouldn't be on the Stack. It seems to continuously execute the CloseFileOperation when the event is triggered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the event handler itself instead of a separate routine, you have access to the FormClosingEventArgs which will allow you to cancel the closing if necessary.  Also you're using `this.Close();`, which just restarts the event, instead of returning and letting the event finish.  When I use this code set as the event handler it works on Win7 as expected:

```
    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if(SpreadSheet.Changed)
        {
            switch(MessageBox.Show("Would you like to save your changes?", "Spreadsheet Utility",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning))
            {
                case DialogResult.Yes:
                    SaveFileOperation();
                    return;
                case DialogResult.No:
                    return;
                case DialogResult.Cancel:
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

My Answer is:

1.Don't call this.close() function as you are already in closing event.

2.if you want to change the closing event action(close or don't close) you can simply set the **FormClosingEventArgs** parameter (e in below code) property **cancel** to **true** to cancel closing  or **false** to close.

3.if sheet is not saved you dont need to do anything , in that case form should be closed simply without prompting. hence you can ignore the else block.

here the modified code is:

> if (SpreadSheet.Changed)
>
> ```
>             {
>                 DialogResult UserChoice = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to save your changes?", "Spreadsheet Utility",MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
>
>                 switch (UserChoice)
>                 {
>                     case DialogResult.Yes:
>                        SaveFileOperation();
>                         break;
>                 case DialogResult.No:
>                     break;
>                 case DialogResult.Cancel:
>                     e.Cancel = true;
>                     break;
> ```