# C# - Override the Standard Windows Close Button to Pop-up my Custom Form

Tags: c#, forms, overriding

Yes, noob question. My apologies.

When users click on the red x button on the window, I want to pop up a message asking if they really would want to quit. I found a similar question on this site: [Override standard close (X) button in a Windows Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669318/override-standard-close-x-button-in-a-windows-form).

The thing is, I want to customize the font and the MessageBoxIcon for the MessageBox, and sadly it can't be done (or will take a lot of effort to be done). So, I've decided to make my own form.

```
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtID.Text != "" || txtPassword.Text != "")
        {
            base.OnFormClosing(e);
            if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown) return;

            // Confirm user wants to close
            new formConfirmExit().ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

I added this code under the main form. However, when I run my code and I click on the standard close button, my pop up (the custom form I did) doesn't do what it's job. Suppose I click the "No" button, it terminates my entire program. With the "Yes" button, the pop-up shows up again, and then everything kinda stops (on Visual Studio) and ta-da! an exception.

BTW, these are the Yes and No button methods (from my Custom Form's class):

```
    private void btnYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit(); // terminate program (exception is in here)
    }

    private void btnNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close(); // close this pop up window and go back to main window
    }
```

Changing `Application.Exit()` to `Environment.Exit(0)` did the job for the Yes button, but my No button, well, terminates the program, still.

Edit: When I click on the Yes button, the pop-up/my custom form shows again (just one time). It'll stay on that state (I can click on the Yes button repeatedly yet nothing happens). The InvalidOperationException is thrown when I click the Yes button first (note the first sentence of this paragraph) then the No button.

Thank you.

Comment: Try this.Hide() instead of this.Close()

Comment: InvalidOperationException.

Comment: user DialogResult in your message box form,assign proper value to in on each button click and close that form. after that check DialogResult value in your main form

Comment: @Imapler: I tried. Doesn't seem to fix it. :(

Comment: @user2767299: Thanks for your idea. I guess the answer I accepted here applied that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your No_Click:

```
private void btnNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = DialogResult.No;
}
```

Then, change your forms closing event to the following:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtID.Text != "" || txtPassword.Text != "")
    {
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown
            || e.CloseReason == CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall)
                return;

        // Confirm user wants to close
        using(var closeForm = new formConfirmExit())
        {
            var result = closeForm.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.No)
                e.Cancel = true;   
        }
    }       
}
```

First, it checks if the form isn't closing through `Application.Exit()`, this may be triggered from your other form, so it will not reshow the custom MessageBox.

Second, you create a using statement around your custom form. This way you can preserve the values. You then set the dialogresult to `no`, if the user doesn't want to cancel. If this is the case, set `e.Cancel = true` to stop from exiting.