# ""object" has no definition for "OnFormClosing" Error on Overriding a System Method

Tags: c#, winforms

I am just trying to override the "OnFormClosing()" method so that it logs a simple string before closing the application.

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        log.Info("File closed");
        base.OnFormClosing(e); 
    }
```

Why is it showing this error

> "object" has no definition for "OnFormClosing"

on the

```
base.OnFormClosing(e);
```

I am trying to implement this inside my `static class Programm{}` but even in every other public class inside my project I get the same error if I try to implement this method there.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: `OnFormClosing` is an event on `Form` type, not your types.

Comment: *"before closing the application"* - look inside `Program` class, you can do such logging after `Application.Run(new SomeForm());` line.

Comment: I don't understand what ure saying here. I was following this sample [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669318/override-standard-close-x-button-in-a-windows-form) . How come that wont work in my project?

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises because the class `Program` (where you try to override this method) inherits from the class `object` and not from the class `Form`. The class object has no `OnFormClosing` method. If you look at the declaration of the class it does not show any inheritance

```
static class Program //<- here is no inheritance specified!
{
```

You need to choose one of your windows `Form` classes and put the code in there. Because a created winform will inherit from the class `Forms`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
```