# Overriding OnFormclosing method

Tags: c#, class, overriding

Im coming from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669318/override-standard-close-x-button-in-a-windows-form) 

I need to do same thing, but i need to put that code in class.
here is code from my class.

```
    public class MyForm : Form
{

    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFormClosing(e);

        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown) return;

        // Confirm user wants to close
        switch (MessageBox.Show(this, "Are you sure you want to close?", "Closing", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
        {
            case DialogResult.No:
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }


}
```

When i remove this function from Form design code and put it in class, its look like compiler doesnt recognize it. The problem is not in code i think

Update:
Lennar , thanks for answer, i know how to add event, but how it should be achieved when i have code in class?

Comment: _"the code doesnt do job"_, what you mean? What you expect to happen and what's actually happening?

Comment: you probably want to remove the base.onFormClosing at least before your code.. but what is it that isnt doing what you want, what have you found while trying to fix it

Comment: You need to register the event using '+='.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

This method is an event handler:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    //code here
}
```

Because it is an event handler for the form, it usually would be raised from the Designer.cs.
So what you need to do is raise the event whenever the form is closing.
To do this:

1. Go to the properties of your form
2. Click on the event icon: [image: event icon]
3. Go to the Behavior section and double click FormClosing: [image: formclosing event]

After doing this, you should see a stub for the event handler in your code in which you can put the function body that you want, and your code should work.