# Is there a Microsoft standard for overloading the closing of a window?

Tags: .net, winforms

I've managed to find lots of information relating to methods of intercepting this event ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669318/override-standard-close-x-button-in-a-windows-form), and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562808/vb-net-overload-default-functionality-when-user-clicks-the-x-close-program)), however I can't actually find any information on windows recommendations for the top right close button.

Are there any clear guidelines towards intercepting the OnFormClose function? The example in question is minimising to system tray, I know its a very specific question, but its to solve an argument.

Comment: Very unclear.  I reckon the recommendation is that you don't override it and let the window close as the user intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear.

There is no `OnFormClose` event.  There are `OnFormClosed` and `OnFormClosing` events, however.

If you're asking, `What should the Close button on a window do?`, then you may find this quote and reference helpful:

> > All primary and secondary windows with a standard window frame should have a Close button on the title bar. Clicking Close has the effect of canceling or closing the window.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511262.aspx

If, however, you are asking what is the best method of intercepting or handling these events, then you could refer to the MSDN documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onformclosed.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onformclosing.aspx

For anything else, I would ask that you clarify your question.